# Save Image to server and reference it via a web address, MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5

When uploading an image it should save to the server which I've accomplished, however I want it to also save to my sql database as a web address so that I can reference the image outside of my application. So I basically want it to upload to the server and then save to the database path as url: *"\admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\Images\ImageName"*

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,CustomerCompanyName,CustomerName,CustomerSurname,CustomerGUID,CustomerStatus,CustomerAddress,CustomerTel,CustomerCel,CustomerNumber,CustomerContact,CustomerLogo,CustomerLogoPath,LastStoreCustomerSyncID")] Customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(file!=null)
                {
                    string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                   string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

                    if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalPath);

                    string physicalFullPath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, ImageName);

                    file.SaveAs(physicalFullPath);

                    customer.CustomerLogo = ImageName;
                    customer.CustomerLogoPath = physicalFullPath;
                    db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.LoyaltyLevelID = new SelectList(db.LoyaltyLevels, "LoyaltyLevelID", "LoyaltyLevelName", customer.LoyaltyLevelID);
            ViewBag.DiscountLevelID = new SelectList(db.DiscountLevels, "DiscountLevelID", "DiscountLevelName", customer.DiscountLevelID);
            return View(customer);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
 customer.CustomerLogoPath = physicalFullPath;
```

with

```
 customer.CustomerLogoPath = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~") + "/Images/" + ImageName;
```

if you want to save `virtual path` of the image instead of its `physical path`.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions saves the path as "http://localhost:64767//Images/LOYALTY-LW.png", I need it to be \admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\Images\LOYALTY-LW.png instead

Comment: Look right now you are running your application at `localhost` that's why it contains host as `localhost` but when you will deploy your application to `admin.loyaltyworx.co.za` then it will automatically add `admin.loyaltyworx.co.za` as host.

Comment: But if you want to save image path with `admin.loyaltyworx.co.za` regardless of current context of request then simply hardcode this string `admin.loyaltyworx.co.za` with image folder and image name like `"admin.loyaltyworx.co.za/Images/" + ImageName` . But method provided in answer is a standard way to do that.